# Redirecting to another view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using the following code to redirect the user to another view controller called `Sub_category`:

```
Sub_category *sub = [[Sub_category alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
sub.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:sub animated:YES];
```

Unfortunately it did not work properly.

I am new to Xcode IDE , so any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `initWithNibName:nil` means you're setting the nib associated with Sub_category to nil, so when you go to present that view there's nothing to show. Try just `[[Sub_category alloc] init];`